# Filter table data based on date using MEAN stack... AngularJS, MongoDB, Mongoose

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, date, filter, html-table

I've got events that I've added to a MondoDB using a form. I'm displaying a list of events, but need all the events to be filtered by date so that only the ones in the future show up in this table (I also have another table for past events). All of my attempts, best one below, have produced no events in my table. I think the Date format or the Schema is not compatible with the one from the form, but I'm a noob, so what do I know. Here is as much code as I thought might be necessary for a whole picture of the puzzle.

Schema:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var EventSchema = new Schema({
    startDate: { type: Date, required: false }
});

mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

Form:

```
<section data-ng-controller="EventsController">
  <p class="page-title">create a new event</p> 
  <form style="float:none; left:25%" name="eventForm" class="form-horizontal col-md-6" role="form" data-ng-submit="create(eventForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && eventForm.date.$invalid }">
      <label for="date" class="col-md-3 control-label">Date</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input name="date" type="date" id="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="form-control glowing-border" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

The important part of my table:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" data-ng-controller="EventsController" data-ng-init="find()">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="event in events | filterList">
            <td>{{event.startDate}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My Module with Controller and custom Filter:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('mean.events');
app.controller('EventsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global', 'Events',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Global, Events) {
    $scope.global = Global;

    $scope.create = function(isValid) {
      if (isValid) {
        var event = new Events({
          startDate: this.date
        });
        event.$save(function(response) {
          $location.path('events/' + response._id);
        });

        this.date = '';
      } else {
        $scope.submitted = true;
      }
    };


    $scope.find = function() {
      Events.query(function(events) {
        $scope.events = events;
      });
    };
  }
]);

app.filter('filterList', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var upcoming = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item){
      if(item.startDate >= new Date()) {
        upcoming.push(item);
      }
    });

    console.log(upcoming);
    return upcoming;
  };
});
```

Comment: Fire up mongo shell, and do commands like "show dbs", "use someDBName" and "show collections" -- try to find your data.  At least you will be able to isolate what layer the issue is in.  Once  you find your collection, do "db.collectionName.find()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem did stem from the date inserted into the DB being of different format than a new Date() object. To fix this, I passed the item.startDate in to new Date() to make them the same. Here is the working filter:

```
app.filter('filterList', function() {
    return function(items) {
        var upcoming = [];

        angular.forEach(items, function(item){
          if ( new Date() > new Date(item.startDate) ) {
              upcoming.push(item);
          }
        });

        return upcoming;
    };
});
```

Comment: Here i had an error "error: [ngmodel:datefmt] expected to be a date" whenever i tried to pass data from the db directly to a data input field. i converted to new date like you said and now works. very clutch, but well thought